# Eclipse, perspectives that change the open files in editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, perspectives

Is it possible to configure eclipse to display different files depending on the perspective?

Say I have a PHP and a PyDev project. In the PHP perspective it would show just my open PHP files. If I switch to the PyDev, it will open up the last python files I had. If I switch back to the PHP perspective, it displays the same PHP files I had open just a minute ago.

This would be beneficial when working on two different projects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it already did this.  What version of eclipse do you have installed?  Of course, I could be wrong.  I've been running two different versions eclipse.  My c++ executable and my Java executable don't share files.

Comment: I am running 3.6.1. I am just using a single binary of eclipse, and a single workspace but multiple projects in different programming languages.

Comment: Unfortunately without switching between different executables I don't know how to manage that.  I don't know of any eclipse extensions that will do the job.